# Custom patch for Nodejs built-in module in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, patch, readline

I'm writing a REPL application using typescript with nodejs's built-in [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module. To build a customized shell, there is a need to change a small piece of implementation of readline's completer. I have found the [source code of readline](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/readline.js) and would like to do a small fix from `output += '\r\n\r\n';` to `output += '\r\n';` at line 665.

I guess an approach is to have a patched version of readline.js and write a type declaration for it. But since readline is a built-in module, too many variables (e.g. `primordials` at line 65) are declared elsewhere and simply rewriting the source file leads to compile error. Redeclaring the module seems to be impractical.

Any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Couldn't you [build your own copy of node](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#building-nodejs) with the change?  I know it seems a little extreme to do that just to remove a return/newline, but I think you're right that there's no easy way of doing this otherwise.

Comment: @RichN I think you are right. I will publish my application in a container which is installed with a revisioned node.js.

Comment: Sounds like a drastic measure for such a small thing. Is it _imperative_ that the completer behaves in that way?

Comment: @AKX I firstly think that there should be an easy and elegant way to perform such fix which I did not know, so I posted the question.

Comment: If that single `\r\n\r\n` is the problem, can't you just rewrite that single function using non-primordials and patch it in? `readline.Interface.prototype._tabComplete = yourCompatibleImplementation`?

Comment: It is difficult since that function requires many other built-in variables.